# Python - Best way to process a JSON-like string

Tags: python

I'm working with a JSON-like string which is structured like this:

```
"CA":"Canada","FR":"France","DE":"Germany","NL":"Netherlands","PL":"Poland","GB":"United Kingdom","AR":"Argentina","AU":"Australia","BE":"Belgium","BR":"Brazil","more":"+26"
```

I'd like to know which is the most optimal way of extracting either values or keys (as this could work for using flag emojis) from this string. I've thought of adding {} to make it a valid JSON and process it that way and using regular expression, but I'd like to know which is the proper way of doing this.

Comment: If you are certain that it will be valid JSON when you prepend a `{` and append a `}`, just do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what you would consider "proper" but the keys and values are in a well-defined pattern.

```
inpstr = '"CA":"Canada","FR":"France","DE":"Germany","NL":"Netherlands",...'

obj = {k.strip('"'): v.strip('"') for k, v in [p.split(':') for p in inpstr.split(',')]}
```

Answer (score 2):

json library may be useful: json.loads() method parses the json string into a dictionary

```
import json

your_string = '"CA":"Canada","FR":"France","DE":"Germany","NL":"Netherlands","PL":"Poland","GB":"United Kingdom","AR":"Argentina","AU":"Australia","BE":"Belgium","BR":"Brazil","more":"+26"'
json_like_string = '{' + your_string + '}'

dict_from_json = json.loads(json_like_string)

print(dict_from_json)
```

output:

```
{'CA': 'Canada', 'FR': 'France', 'DE': 'Germany', 'NL': 'Netherlands', 'PL': 'Poland', 'GB': 'United Kingdom', 'AR': 'Argentina', 'AU': 'Australia', 'BE': 'Belgium', 'BR': 'Brazil', 'more': '+26'}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is where json.dumps() helps you, you change it into json like format. [w3schools dumps documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_json.asp)